# load image before the script

Tags: jquery, image, load

I have a script for resizing the background image for every pages. It happens that sometimes e slower machines and pages with lots of content(other images) the background image becomes stretched.

Inittialy I had this

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    ...code for resizing the image...
});
```

and the I decided that the code it's executed just after the image(with the id img_bg) is loaded, so:

```
$("#img_bg").ready(function() {
  ...code for resizing the image...
});
```

I got better results, but still not perfect as I wanted.

Does anyone has any other ideas??

Thanks

Answer (score 2):

According to the jquery documentation [1] *.ready()* really only executes after the element is fully loaded.
So your problem may be, that there is a ceratin time until your resizing script has finished it's job. (especially if other things are to be processed simultaniously) One way to solve this would be to simply hide the image until your resizing is done.
Use the  *show* [2] function in the end of your scaling method and initially set `display="none"` in your css for `#img_bg` for that purpose.

However you should think about your whole setup. It is never really clever to load a large image and then resacle it with javascript if you would only use a smaller one. Then it might be better to have a smaller one initially (to save bandwith and therefore increase loading speed)

And an other thought is that this resizing most likely could be achieved with a clever use of some css instead of javascript. But therefore you would have to provide some more details about how your script actually works and what it's doing.

[1] http://api.jquery.com/ready/

[2] http://api.jquery.com/show/

Comment: thanks for the explanation. Very Useful. About resizing the image with css I already tried in the past but with out as success as the javascript. What it does is a comparison between the width and height values of the browser and adjust the width or height of the image. Then position the center of the image in the center of the browser canvas and finally call for the window.resize function. As soon I get to my computer I'll try your tip about hide and the show the image after the resize is done. Thanks a lot

Answer (score 0):

If you place the javascript code immediately after your div/html control then it will still execute when the control is ready, you do not need a "ready" statement.

A document.ready is simply to signify that all HTML is loaded and you can do anything with the dom, but you can modify elements before the entire page is ready.

Comment: But all the pages of the website site needs the functions that resize the image.And this function its not a 3-5lines, it has around 40lines. I dont't think that is very correct to put all that code in every single page. Thanks